# How can i add the out of the box column "Created By" to my Content Type using VS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm creating a SharePoint Add-In and was wondering how can i add the existing column "Created By" . I can add it manually when the list is deployed and go to settings but i would like to be there in my list when it is deployed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This field is automatically part of each content type. As well ass date fields (Created and Modified).
Base your CT on List item or Document and you will have all the desired fields.

Comment: Actually adding the item content type doesn't change anything. List item cannot be found. Can anyone just find me the Title of the column and the ID and add it manually to the schema?

Comment: Can you post your CT ID?

Comment: Content Type ID is 0x01008EB5FB2464CE4450A956CDE6EC2AE903 . The thing is i can't add the created by column to my content type or list. If i had the out of the box ID for the created by column i could add manually to the schema of the content type